# Retrieving the selected nodes doesn't show up

Tags: angular, primeng, angular8

Hi I'm using the **Primeng tree checkbox multiselct**. In which got some issues with retrieving the saved tree values in edit mode..

**files: TreeNode[];**

**selectedFiles: TreeNode[] = [];**

Normally we can use some backed service which returns data as **TreeNode** format to easily bind the values to [Value] property. In the same way i used for to retrieve values in [(selection)]="selectedFiles" property but it doesn't showed up the selected nodes.. any answers..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `key` value for each TreeNode. When you retrieve the data from backend you likely have a backend id for each item. The easiest way is to simply assign this id to `key`.